# derailed in solving the convergence of $\int_{x=2}^\infty \frac{1}{xe^x} dx$ with a Taylor expansion

Tags: calculus, convergence-divergence, improper-integrals

I'm trying to reason through whether $\int_{x=2}^\infty \frac{1}{xe^x} dx$  converges.

Intuitively, It would seem that since $\int_{x=2}^\infty \frac{1}{x} dx$ diverges, then multiplying the denominator by something to make it smaller would make it converge.

If I apply a Taylor expansion to the $\frac{1}{e^x}$, then I get

$\displaystyle \int_{x=2}^\infty \frac{1}{x} e^{-x} dx = \int_{x=2}^\infty \frac{1}{x}(1 + (-x) + \frac{(-x)^2}{2} + \cdots) dx$

My initial thought was to multiply everything out and just look at the leading order behavior, $ x^{n-1}$, but this would seem to mean the integral diverges.

What is wrong with this approach?

Comment: The exponential function dominates! $1/x$ is bounded by $1/2$.

Comment: Also, you can Taylor-expand in the denominator, $\dfrac{1}{xe^x} = \dfrac{1}{x(1 + x + \frac{x^2}{2} + \frac{x^3}{3!} + \dotsb)} < \dfrac{1}{x(1+x)} < \dfrac{1}{x^2}$. Since all terms in the Taylor expansion are positive, you can truncate the expansion to get an estimate.

Comment: Your approach makes the problem too hard, that's what's wrong with it!  Read the answers.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just notice that,

$$ x \geq 2 \implies \frac{1}{x}\leq \frac{1}{2}\implies \frac{1}{xe^{x}}\leq \frac{1}{2e^{x}}= \frac 1 2 e^{-x}. $$

So you can compare with the function $ \frac 1 2 e^{-x} $.

Comment: Remember you also need to bound it from below. I know this is extremely easy, and simple. But it is an essential point. Eg $1/e^x \cdot e^x\leq 1/xe^x \leq 1/2e^x$

Comment: @N3buchadnezzar, is bounding from below necessary with positive functions?

Comment: If you do not say/show that the function is strictly positive then yes ;) And when you say that the function is strictly positive in reality you *are* bounding it from below so..

Answer (score 3):

Using the Taylor expansion was fine, the problem is in the "leading order" approach.

You chose to express $\frac{1}{e^x}$ as an *infinite* sum - you cannot truncate it for no reason.

Comment: Is there a way to solve it without truncation?

Comment: @maogenc solve what? You have been offered many other solutions.

Answer (score 2):

I believe the easiest thing to do here is note that for all $x\geq 2$ one has $\frac{1}{xe^x}\leq e^{-x}$.

As for your approach, beyond what @user1337 rightfully said, note that we can't just decide that everything (asymptotically-)smaller than $\frac{1}{x}$ yields a converging integral, because (for example)
$$\int_2^\infty\frac{dx}{x\log x}=\infty.$$
However, it is true that
$$\int_2^\infty\frac{dx}{x(\log x)^{1+\epsilon}}<\infty,$$
so every function which grows at least as fast as $(\log x)^{1+\epsilon}$ (which includes, as we already know by the standard $p$-test, $x^\epsilon$) would do, so $e^x$ surely works.

Comment: @MhenniBenghorbal had me.

Answer (score 2):

The Taylor expansion works. Note from $e^x=1+x+\frac{x^2}{2!}+\cdots$, we have $e^x\gt x$ for positive $x$.

It follows that 
$$\frac{1}{xe^x}\lt \frac{1}{x^2}.$$
But we know that $\displaystyle\int_2^\infty \frac{1}{x^2}\,dx$ converges, and therefore by Comparison so does our integral.

As has been pointed out, there are better ways to handle the problem without using the Taylor series.

Comment: I don't know about the last comment, until now all of the answers including this are based on estimates - as I see it. (+1 anyway)

Comment: Convergence, for integrals of positive functions, is all about decay rate. One can see at a glance that the function decays faster than $\frac{1}{e^x}$, which is plenty fast enough.

Comment: No that is not true. There are positive functions that are unbounded at infinity but with convergent integral.

Comment: Well, I meant only to comment the first part of your comment, the second statement is fine. :)

Comment: Certainly. Though it remains true if we think in terms of average decay rate. And in the standard convergence questions asked in first courses, it is absolutely decay rate.